# py-cord on_member_join() event doesnt works

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my code:

```
import discord
from discord import Option
from datetime import datetime

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True


bot = discord.Bot(
    intents=intents,
    debug_guilds=[GUILD-IDs]
    
)


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{datetime.utcnow()} {member} has joined {member.guild.name}, Server ID: {member.guild.id}')
    with open('join-log.txt', 'a') as joinlog:
        joinlog.writelines(f'{datetime.utcnow()} {member} has joined {member.guild.name}, Server ID: {member.guild.id}\n')

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

(I am using py-cord)

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 382, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_member_join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

The weird thing is that the same code works perfectly fine the function `on_member_remove()`

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
Delete py-cord and install the newest version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the correct intents enabled in your script and Discord developer account. To read messages and see members the bot needs message and members intents. At the moment your script can't see server members which is why you get the error. Add this to your script and enable the intents in your developer account:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

bot = discord.Client(intents=intents, members = True, messages = True, message_content = True)
```